# How to forward expired messages on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus topic `back2gq`. I've configured EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration and forwarding to a queue called `dlq`. The messages on `dlq` are consumed by a monitoring service. My intention was to detect when a client has stopped processing messages (due to crash or disconnect).

My messages have a TTL of four seconds. The default TTL for the subscription is ten seconds. However, the messages don't get forwarded to the `dlq` after ten seconds.

I've used the Azure Service Bus Explorer to see what is going on:
[image]

The messages start piling up if there are no clients actively listening on the topic. All messages stay marked as 'active' and don't expire. After approximately 120 seconds all messages are flushed to the `dlq` in one go... 
I had expected to see an incremental increase either on the DeadLetter count of `back2gw` or the message count on `dlq`.

[The Service Bus documentation states (emphasis mine):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration)

> The expiration for any individual message can be controlled by setting the TimeToLive system property, which specifies a relative duration. The expiration becomes an absolute instant when the message is enqueued into the entity. At that time, the ExpiresAtUtc property takes on the value (EnqueuedTimeUtc + TimeToLive). **The time-to-live (TTL) setting on a brokered message is not enforced when there are no clients actively listening**.

In the next paragraph it goes on to say:

> All messages sent into a queue or topic are subject to a default expiration that is set at the entity level with the defaultMessageTimeToLive property and which can also be set in the portal during creation and adjusted later.

I interpret this to mean that messages should still expire after defaultMessageTimeToLive is exceeded even if there aren't any active clients. Is the observed behavior correct? Did I misunderstand the docs? I'm on the Standard plan, is this perhaps Premium feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

Expired messages  will eventually be moved to the DeadLetter queue (and subsequently forwarded if configured accordingly), but it you cannot depend on when exactly that happens.

[The chapter about message browsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-browsing) mentions (emphasis mine):

> Consumed and **expired messages are cleaned up by an asynchronous
>   "garbage collection" run and not necessarily exactly when messages
>   expire**, and therefore Peek may indeed return messages that have
>   already expired and will be removed or dead-lettered when a receive
>   operation is next invoked on the queue or subscription.

This periodic cleanup behavior matches my observation.